# How do I inherit a constructor from base class in CPP?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to do an inheritance problem. I have a base class Animal with parameters int height, age, and weight. I also have a default constructor and a constructor with parameters. I have a derived class Dog with the parameter dogType and a constructor with the parameters from Animal and the new parameter, dogType. My question is, how do I use the constructor w/ parameters from Animal for the Dog class? This is how I tried to do it, however, it is not working. I will include all the header and implementation files. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Animal
{
private:
    int height;
    int age;
    int weight;
public:
    Animal();
    Animal(int h, int a, int w);
    void print()const;
};
```

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include <iostream>

Animal::Animal()
{
    height = 0;
    age = 0; 
    weight = 0;
}
Animal::Animal(int h, int a, int w)
{
    height = h;
    age = a;
    weight = w;
}
void Animal::print()const
{
    std::cout << "Height:" << height << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Age:" << age << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Weight:" << weight << std::endl;
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include "Animal.h"
#include <iostream>

class Dog :
    public Animal
{
private:
    std::string dogType;
public:
    Dog();
    Dog(int h, int a, int w, std::string dt);
    void print()const;
};
```

```
#include "Dog.h"

Dog::Dog()
{

}
Dog::Dog(int h, int a, int w, std::string dt) 
{
    Animal::Animal(h, a, w);
    dogType = dt;

}
void Dog::print()const
{
    Animal::print();
    std::cout << "Dog Type:" << dogType << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html). See [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and the [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) C++ standard. Look for examples of C++ source code on [github](http://github.com/) and [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/) e.g. [Qt](https://qt.io/) - I happen to have written some of them. If your C++ compiler is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), read its documentation and invoke it as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. See also [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for inheriting is

```
Dog::Dog() : Animal()
{
}

Dog::Dog(int h, int a, int w, const std::string& dt) 
   : Animal(h, a, w), dogtype{dt}
{
}
```

Since `Dog()` is an empty constructor you could define with

```
Dog::Dog() = default
```

The proper way to define the `Animal` constructor instead is:

```
Animal::Animal()
   : Animal(0,0,0)
{
}

Animal::Animal(int h, int a, int w)
  : height{h}, age{a}, weight{w}
{
}
```

First one is using [**delegate constructor**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor#Delegating_constructor) and second one is using constructor [**initializer list**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: You might want to mention [Initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: @ZachSal please mark it as accepted is the answer is fine for you

Comment: @Moia Thank you so much for the help. I plan on getting a cpp book to help me understand the syntax better. If you don't mind me asking, what exactly does the colon do? Also, why is it better to use : Animal(0,0,0) instead of how I had it? Again, thank you so much for the help. I think I marked your response as the answer.

Comment: @ZachSal read the link about the initializer list. Using the delegate constructor is to be less bug-prone. In this way only one constructor is the delegate of the initialization and the others refer to that. Multiple constructor could lead to unintended different behaviour if you implement the construction in any of those

Answer (score 1):

@Moia already had the correct syntax you should use for initializing your `Dog` object.

The reason your code didn't work is because when the code goes to `Animal::Animal(h, a, w)`, the underlying `Animal` of your `Dog` is already initialized.

In fact, all members in your class, include all member from your parent class have already been initialized when you have entered the first line of your constructor. Unless you have done a initializer list or delegate constructor like @Moia has mentioned, they will be default initialized.

By writing `Animal::Animal(h, a, w)` here, you are just creating a temporary `Animal` object, that will never be used.

While you could still changed the `height`, `age`, and other things if you have provided setter functions for them, it is better to use initializer list because you will not be initializing them first, then changing the value of them.